# foreign key relationship is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here I am doing foreign key relation for my SQL, I am having 3 tables

1. product
2. gallery
3. offer

Here `product` table is a master table and `gallery`, `offer` tables are child table, now I trying to delete the master table entry but it not happening I am getting an error like

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
    CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `regOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin

CREATE TABLE `offer` (
 `offerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `offerpercentage` text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`offerId`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 CONSTRAINT `offer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productId`) REFERENCES `product` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin

CREATE TABLE `gallery` (
 `galleryId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `galleryName` text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`galleryId`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 CONSTRAINT `gallery_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productId`) REFERENCES `product` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin
```

> Expected output

```
Suppose I am deleting master table entry means i have to delete all child tables entry also
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your foreign key references.

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `regOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin

CREATE TABLE `offer` (
 `offerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `offerpercentage` text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`offerId`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 CONSTRAINT `offer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productId`) REFERENCES `product` (`productId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin

CREATE TABLE `gallery` (
 `galleryId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `galleryName` text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`galleryId`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 CONSTRAINT `gallery_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productId`) REFERENCES `product` (`productId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin
```

This tells MySQL that when the parent is deleted, delete the referencing child.